# How do I generate a number of random numbers that are all odd

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

myfile = open('numbers.txt', 'w')
file_size = random.randint(4,7)

for count in range(file_size):
    numbers = random.randint(5,19)
    myfile.write(str(numbers) + '\n')

myfile.close()
```

This what I have so far, but I need the numbers to be all odds and the right amount of odds that the "file_size" is telling the code.
Each integer must be random, between 5 and 19 inclusive.

Comment: use `random.randrange(start,end,step)` and have a step of `2` and start on an odd number

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) which accepts optional `step` parameter:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.randrange(5, 19+1, 2)
9
```

Answer (score 2):

To generate an odd number between 1 and 10 use `random.randrange(start,end,step)`

```
odd_rand_num = random.randrange(1,10,2)
odd_rand_num = 7
```

To generate a list of random odd numbers please use this:

```
odd_rand_list = [random.randrange(1,10,2) for p in range(0,10)]
odd_rand_list = [3, 9, 7, 9, 1, 1, 9, 7, 3, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, floor division by two plus one

> 2*(k//2)+1

will always give you an odd number...

```
import random
odd = 2*(random.randint(5,19)//2)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach :

```
import random

with open('numbers.txt', 'w') as myfile:
    file_size = random.randint(4,7)

    for count in range(file_size):
        numbers = random.choice(range(5, 19+1, 2))
        myfile.write(str(numbers) + '\n')
```

Correction in OP Code:

```
import random

myfile = open('numbers.txt', 'w')
file_size = random.randint(4, 7)

for count in range(file_size):
    while True:
        number = random.randint(5, 19)
        if number % 2 == 1:
            break
    myfile.write(str(number) + '\n')

myfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `random.randrange()` function, and start from an odd number like:

```
import random
for i in range(40):
    x = random.randrange(3, n, 3)
    print(f"{x}/3:\t", x/3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use randrange as follows:

```
import random as rn
a = rn.randrange(0,100,2)
b = a + 1
print (b)
```

Comment: Good answer but you it can probably be made more clear. Why use 0 to 100 with a skip of 2 and adding 1 rather than just 1 to 100 with a skip of 2? `random.randrange(5, 20, 2)` is all that is needed, I think. (a stop of 20 because the stop is exclusive, and we want to include 19) https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange